# Is there a way to make FB and Google OAuth logins work in desktop build/simulator?

Tags: codenameone

These are broken in the simulator and desktop builds. I saw somewhere that someone had "fixed" them by manually parsing the embedded browser that hosts them and editing some html content

Is there a cleaner solution or one that can be explained in more detail? @Shai will this be fixed in the future? Desktop builds are a huge benefit of pro subscriptions and would probably balance the scale for many to pay for it. But social logins are commonplace today and you can't expect mobile users to create separate logins for desktop versions of the same application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simulator you can use the credentials for the web login and this should work just fine e.g.:

```
Button facebook = new Button("Facebook", Resources.getGlobalResources().getImage("facebook.png"), "FlagButton");
add(facebook);

facebook.addActionListener(e -> {
    final Login fb = FacebookConnect.getInstance();
    fb.setClientId("....");
    fb.setClientSecret("....");
    fb.setRedirectURI("https://www.codenameone.com/");
    fb.setCallback(new LoginCallback() {
        @Override
        public void loginFailed(String errorMessage) {
            ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Login failed: " + errorMessage);
        }

        @Override
        public void loginSuccessful() {                    
            String token = fb.getAccessToken().getToken();
            Response<Map> resp = Rest.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me").
                    queryParam("access_token", token).
                    acceptJson().getAsJsonMap();
            String userId = (String)resp.getResponseData().get("id");
            new EnterPasswordForm(null, userId, null).show();
        }
    });
    fb.doLogin();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was calling isUserLoggedIn() before doLogin() and this wasn't supported in the simulator. Do you have an example of a Google Login in the simulator? Currently, jI am able to display the login browser that asks for your email address but clicking next does nothing

Comment: Google login is the exact same thing with `GoogleConnect` instead of `FacebookConnect`.